# Why are there aliasing drawings with gdi?

Tags: svg, bitmap, gdi

Why are there aliasing drawings with gdi? And even don't scale it.

If I don't scale it, I think it won't be aliased.

And draw a circle with SVG will not be aliased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by "sawtooth" you mean [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). GDI is about 30 years old. Since antialiasing requires quite a lot of computation power it's support has never been added. It is technically [possible to draw smooth images using GDI and some additional code](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/21520/antialiasing-using-windows-gdi), however it is better to use newer API that supports antialiasing out of box, such as Direct2D or at least GDI+.

Also svg is just an xml-based file format. You don't "draw" anything with svg, you just describe image with svg and then it gets rendered with some rendering engine, such as cairo. If you render svg using plain GDI you'll still get aliased image.

Comment: Thanks for your explain.